# How do I clear element values from an array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

Here I have an array.

```js
  let dataList=  [
  {
    "VersionId": 475,
    "DocumentVersionFieldId": 1105,
    "VariantId": 4597,
    "ElementId": 1019,
    "FuelTypeId": 4,
    "VariantStructureWeek": "201817",
    "SalesVersion": "1",
    "MarketingCode": "1",
    "Option": "1",
    "SequenceNo": 1,
    "VariantExtendedValue": [],    
    "cocVariantElementValues": [
      {
        "VersionId": 475,
        "DocumentVersionFieldId": 1105,
        "VariantId": 4597,
        "ElementId": 1017,
        "ElementVariantId": 9548,
        "VariantValue": "uy",
        "IsRecordVisible": false,
        "cocElementLanguageDataCollection": [
          {
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "LanguageId": 0,
            "LanguageCode": "EN",
            "TranslationValue": "uy"
          },
          {
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "LanguageId": 0,
            "LanguageCode": "AL",
            "TranslationValue": "jh"
          },
          {
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "LanguageId": 0,
            "LanguageCode": "DE",
            "TranslationValue": "hj"
          },          
          {
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "LanguageId": 0,
            "LanguageCode": "UR",
            "TranslationValue": "jh"
          }
        ]
      }
    
    ],
    "isRowDeleted": false,
    "operationIndicators": 0,
    "isMultiLanguage": true,
    "IsRecordVisible": true,
    "isShowUp": false,
    "IsNewRow": false
  }
]
```

---

I want to clear value of the below elements from the above array.

- I want to clear `VariantValue` element from `cocVariantElementValues` array
- I want to clear `TranslationValue` element from `cocElementLanguageDataCollection` array

This below is the expected one.

```js
    [
      {
        "VersionId": 475,
        "DocumentVersionFieldId": 1105,
        "VariantId": 4597,
        "ElementId": 1019,
        "FuelTypeId": 4,
        "VariantStructureWeek": "201817",
        "SalesVersion": "1",
        "MarketingCode": "1",
        "Option": "1",
        "SequenceNo": 1,
        "VariantExtendedValue": [],    
        "cocVariantElementValues": [
          {
            "VersionId": 475,
            "DocumentVersionFieldId": 1105,
            "VariantId": 4597,
            "ElementId": 1017,
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "VariantValue": "",//here
            "IsRecordVisible": false,
            "cocElementLanguageDataCollection": [
              {
                "ElementVariantId": 9548,
                "LanguageId": 0,
                "LanguageCode": "EN",
                "TranslationValue": "",//here
              },
              {
                "ElementVariantId": 9548,
                "LanguageId": 0,
                "LanguageCode": "AL",
                "TranslationValue": "",//here
              },
              {
                "ElementVariantId": 9548,
                "LanguageId": 0,
                "LanguageCode": "DE",
                "TranslationValue": "",//here
              },          
              {
                "ElementVariantId": 9548,
                "LanguageId": 0,
                "LanguageCode": "UR",
                "TranslationValue": "",//here
              }
            ]
          }
        
        ],
        "isRowDeleted": false,
        "operationIndicators": 0,
        "isMultiLanguage": true,
        "IsRecordVisible": true,
        "isShowUp": false,
        "IsNewRow": false
      }
    ]
```

> Is there a straightforward way, or do I need to loop through it and remove them manually?

Comment: Could you please let me know the reason for down vote??

Comment: You can use array foreach to do it.

Comment: @HassanImam  is it possible without foreach in ECMascript 6?

Comment: No, in some way you require looping.

Comment: @RameshRajendran hope you can accept my answer :)

Comment: @PPL But your answer is  just only for the HINT. not a exact answer buddy.  Just did +1 only.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I think SO is just for HINT, How can we provide exact solution without proper code

Comment: @PPL Why you are expecting proper code for **particularly  this question???** I have an array i just need transfer to an another array. see my answer. How can i don without proper code.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I'm not expecting code, leave it, I think SO is for helping each other or even by accepting my answer you will not lose any thing but I glad

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thank you so much

Comment: @PPL Don't worry. Any way your answer is  helps to solve it. So I glad to accept that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this without looping over the all elements, however there are some shortcuts you can use instead of for:

```
array.map(function(x) { 
  x['VariantValue'] = ''; 
  return x
});
```

Alternatively you can use this too, it is es6 fat arrow function

```
array.map(x=>x['VariantValue']='');
```

There might be some syntax errors in the above code as it is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @ppl

I got it by using multiple `.map()` for my scenario.

```
dataList.map(function(x) { 
      x.cocVariantElementValues.map(function(y) { 
      y['VariantValue'] = ''; 
      y.cocElementLanguageDataCollection.map(function(z) { 
      z['TranslationValue'] = ''; 
      return z
    });
      return y;
    });
      return x;
    });
```

### Successful Snippet

```js
let dataList=  [
  {
    "VersionId": 475,
    "DocumentVersionFieldId": 1105,
    "VariantId": 4597,
    "ElementId": 1019,
    "FuelTypeId": 4,
    "VariantStructureWeek": "201817",
    "SalesVersion": "1",
    "MarketingCode": "1",
    "Option": "1",
    "SequenceNo": 1,
    "VariantExtendedValue": [],    
    "cocVariantElementValues": [
      {
        "VersionId": 475,
        "DocumentVersionFieldId": 1105,
        "VariantId": 4597,
        "ElementId": 1017,
        "ElementVariantId": 9548,
        "VariantValue": "uy",
        "IsRecordVisible": false,
        "cocElementLanguageDataCollection": [
          {
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "LanguageId": 0,
            "LanguageCode": "EN",
            "TranslationValue": "uy"
          },
          {
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "LanguageId": 0,
            "LanguageCode": "AL",
            "TranslationValue": "jh"
          },
          {
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "LanguageId": 0,
            "LanguageCode": "DE",
            "TranslationValue": "hj"
          },          
          {
            "ElementVariantId": 9548,
            "LanguageId": 0,
            "LanguageCode": "UR",
            "TranslationValue": "jh"
          }
        ]
      }
    
    ],
    "isRowDeleted": false,
    "operationIndicators": 0,
    "isMultiLanguage": true,
    "IsRecordVisible": true,
    "isShowUp": false,
    "IsNewRow": false
  }
]

let result = dataList.map(function(x) { 
  x.cocVariantElementValues.map(function(y) { 
  y['VariantValue'] = ''; 
  y.cocElementLanguageDataCollection.map(function(z) { 
  z['TranslationValue'] = ''; 
  return z
});
  return y;
});
  return x;
});

console.log(result)
```